# Force Android device to use material time picker

Tags: android, datetime, huawei-mobile-services

Is it possible to set an Android device (phone) 
to always use the material time picker?

I know an app can use a different time picker, but 
can I set my phone to always use the round one?

James

Comment: If you mean all the apps installed in the device will be forced to use the time picker with the material theme, then the answer is no.

Comment: ok - thanks - that's a shame, but at least I know.